# How do I get a param which is a part of a URL?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I need to get the param out of a URL:

```
demo.com/market/usdeur
```

I need to define the market according to the value from the URL. I am able to do it with:

```
?market=usdeur

@market = Global[params[:market]]
```

but not when only having the URL available. What I am missing?

This is what I have so far:

```
 params do
    use :market
  end
  get "/:market" do
    @market =  params[:market]
  end
```

Comment: Do you think you can phrase your question a bit differently?  I'm not really sure I understand.

Comment: Are you sure this is rails? It looks like sinatra

Comment: I agree with @BroiSatse and second her statement as I was just about to tell you you need a route when you updated with a `sinatra` style route in which case it would be `get /market/:market` to access it appropriately.

Comment: It also does not work for me when I have `get /market/:market` unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a route for this since it looks like Sinatra and not Rails. Have you tried

```
get '/market/:market' do
  @market = params[:market]
end
```

In Rails it would be more like this in `routes.rb`

```
get '/market/:market', to: 'markets#show', as: :market_path
```

Or something similar.

Right now to access that route you would have to visit `http://www.example.com/usdeur` when what you want is `http://www.example.com/market/usdeur`

**Update**

If this is truly Rails, add the above route to `routes.rb` and then in the `MarketController` add this

```
def show
  #I used #find_by_name not exactly sure what attribute usdeur refers to so you might
  #need to change this
  @market = Market.find_by_name(params[:market]) 
end
```

Now `@market` will be an instance of `Market` given `usdeur` is the `name`.

Comment: @engeersmnky - i have the routes already added in routes.rb however static: `get '/market/viabtc'` - i changed it now to your version and now I get an error: 'undefined method `get' for #<MarketController:0xb3920f28>'

Comment: @domi771 why do you have `get` in your controller this is for routing purposes to respond to `GET` requests? If this is truly rails I have updated my answer

Comment: @domi771 no problem although I am not sure where you got the `sinatra` routing concept from. Take a look at [Rails Routing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for future reference.